# How to get float bit representation without UB in C++?

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing, type-punning, stdlaunder

As far as I know, all 'traditional' ways of doing this, namely `reinterpret_cast` of a pointer and `union` with `int` and `float` fields are UB as violation of strict aliasing ([in C++, not in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior/11996970#11996970)).
So, how to do it correctly without undefined behavior?

Can I do a `reinterpret_cast` to `char *` and memcpy that to uint32_t? Or maybe`std::launder` will help?

Comment: If all you want to do is “get” the bit representation, you can simply convert a pointer to the `float` to `const unsigned char *` and use the resulting pointer to examine the bytes of the object. But why do you mention “memcpy that to float”? Copying to a `float` is not getting the bit representation; it is changing the bits. What do you really want to do?

Comment: There was an [1h talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qzMpk-22cc) about this problem on cppcon 2019. You might be interested in it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yeah, sorry, I meant 'memcpy to uint32_t`, I'll edit the question.

Comment: `memcpy that to uint32_t` - why would you do that to print bits? You can  print them from `char`.

Comment: @KamilCuk well, I want to have them as a single continuous thingy, to get significand and exponent; getting them from char array will be a bit tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to do it, as pointed out by [Jason Turner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L06nbZXD2D0), is to use `memcpy`:

```
float f = 1.0;
std::byte c[sizeof(f)];
memcpy(c, &f, sizeof(f));
```

You may be thinking that you do not want to copy anything, that you just want to see the bits/bytes. Well the compilers are smart and they will in fact optimize it away as demonstrated by Jason so do not worry and use `memcpy` for this kind of thing and never `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: C++20 [`std::bit_cast()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) deserves a mention here.

Comment: Exactly! That is going to be THE standard way of doing this.

Comment: I'm not afraid of copies, I'm afraid of undefined behavior :) Thanks! And what about `std::launder`?

Comment: @Amomum `std::laundr`s return type is the same as its argument type. So conversion from `float` to `unsigned` is not possible.

Comment: @Timo what about `std::launder(reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(f))`?

Comment: @Amomum why use `laundr` in the first place then? To quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) on `std::laundr`: *"the type of X is the same as T"* (where X is the object pointed to).

Comment: @Timo I'm just trying to understand if using `launder` will make such cast or union usage legal.

Comment: @Amomum - It won't. That's not the intended use case, and digging into the wording leaves it still undefined to use the pointer.

Comment: @Amomum - Still no. `launder` deals only with objects within their lifetime. In a union, the object you *want* is not within its lifetime.